# ssl certificate to the AD password change

Tags: ssl, ldap, certificate

I'm sing Java and tring to change the password in AD. I have imported the certificate to the server, but I get an error in the certificate.

Import's valid:

```
keytool -import -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\security\cacerts" -trustcacerts -alias openldap -file "C:\certnew.cer"
```

List's valid:

```
keytool -list -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\security\cacerts"
```

My code:

```
public class PassChange
{
    public static void main (String[] args) {

    Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
    String userName = "CN=optimus,DC=ad,DC=euclid,DC=com";

    String oldPassword = "euclid!23";
    String newPassword = "kcube!23";

    //Could also do this via command line java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore....

    String keystore = "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre6\\lib\\security\\cacerts";

    // 1    String keystore = "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre6\\lib\\security\\cacerts";
    // 2    String keystore = "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre6\\lib\\security\\cacerts.jks";
    // 3    String keystore = "c:\\";
    // 1,2,3 all error

    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", keystore);

    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    //set security credentials, note using simple cleartext authentication
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION,"simple");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL,userName);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS,oldPassword);

    //specify use of ssl
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL,"ssl");

    //connect to my domain controller
    String ldapURL = "ldaps://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:636";
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,ldapURL);

    try {

        // Create the initial directory context
        LdapContext ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env,null);

        //change password is a single ldap modify operation
        //that deletes the old password and adds the new password
        ModificationItem[] mods = new ModificationItem[2];
        String oldQuotedPassword = "\"" + oldPassword + "\"";
        byte[] oldUnicodePassword = oldQuotedPassword.getBytes("UTF-16LE");
        String newQuotedPassword = "\"" + newPassword + "\"";
        byte[] newUnicodePassword = newQuotedPassword.getBytes("UTF-16LE");

        mods[0] = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REMOVE_ATTRIBUTE, new BasicAttribute("unicodePwd", oldUnicodePassword));
        mods[1] = new ModificationItem(DirContext.ADD_ATTRIBUTE, new BasicAttribute("unicodePwd", newUnicodePassword));

        ctx.modifyAttributes(userName, mods);

        System.out.println("Changed Password for: " + userName);    
        ctx.close();

    } 
    catch (NamingException e) {
        System.err.println("Problem changing password: " + e);
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        System.err.println("Problem encoding password: " + e);
    }
}
}
```

Error message:

> problem changing password: javax.naming.CommunicationException: simple bind failed:   xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:636 [Root exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:  sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target]

Comment: To analyze, what is the problem with SSL certificates, try to run the program with additional property javax.net.debug=all. Then update your post with the debugging output. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html as well.

Comment: javax.net.debug=all mode                                         .............  last line error -------------------------------------> Thread-0, called closeSocket()
Thread-0, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Answer (score 0):

Which certificate did you import?  You do NOT want the servers certificate.  Rather you want the public key of the Certificate Authority.  Specifically the switch `-trustcacerts` is meant to indicate this is a CA public key.

Guessing by the name, I wonder if you grabbed the certificate of the server.

Comment: Answer Thank you ^ ^  I have a server certificate.
Issued the certificate from the server to the client was using copy.
If so, do I need a certification authority's public key?

Comment: @user2436284 The client, for LDAP over SSL access should have in the JRE's cacerts file, a trusted CA cert for your CA.  The keytool switch during import that matters is `-trustcacerts`